# Does it save more memory and is it more efficient to reuse recyclerviews?

Tags: java, android, memory-management, heap-memory

I have a total of 4 recyclerviews, each with currently has its own xml recyclerview, is it better on the memory usage to have all 4 fragments use 1 xml recyclerview or each have its own recyclerview? If I change this will it have a substantial effect on the amount of allocated files in my heap?

Answer (score 1):

A few things to point out here:

- Every fragment has a unique view hierarchy. If you want all four fragments to have a recycler view, you should declare it in each fragment. Even if you reuse the save XML defined view between the fragments, a different instance of the recycler view will still be created for each fragment.
- There is no such thing as an XML recycler view. XML is just used as a markup language to specify you view hierarchy. In the end, all the views are Java objects.
- Files are not allocated on the heap. Objects are.

Comment: I see, so are objects that are not called on allocated in heaps? I need to reduce my heap load, where should I start?

Comment: In short - every time you call a constructor using the `new` keyword, you allocate memory on the heap. Other operations can also implicitly create objects. These include autoboxing, string manipulations, etc. If you are not familiar with those terms - look them up first. The best way to monitor what's happening with your memory allocation is using your IDE's profiling tool and see how many object do you create and where do you create them. Problems will be easily identifiable once you examine the results.